# Identity management and authentication for REST APIs

Tags: python, rest, restful-authentication

We have built a Python based REST API. We are planning to give to other developers as well. Is there a Python library which could manage authentication keep track of API calls made be each client etc?

Answer (score 1):

Well, ideally you'll be using [public-key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography), supplying the developers with an API key and secret both. If the service is accessible via HTTPS to a limited number of consumers, you might be tempted to defer to issuing a simple API key alone, but your committing yourself to remain a small, closed and insecure service forever.

As for managing API calls themselves, since you have the RESTful interfaces developed already, I would suggest that you begin decorating the functions or methods to extract the service consumer and keep track of API calls in [MonogoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/)--it's simple and perfectly tuned for such a requirement. It would also allow you to start throttling consumer connections at the application level where, in time, you can develop the system to encompass some low-level solutions for managing service connections, such as `iptables`.